# jupyter notebook double output

Tags: double, output, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a problem with double output! It irritates me.
[image]

It happens with every output. Please help!

Comment: This is happening to me, too. (Using latest Jupyter with latest macOS default Python 2.7)

Answer (score 21):

I've fixed this by restarting the kernel and the re-loading the web page (i.e. F5).

Comment: Restarting the kernel was insufficient for me. I had to close the notebook, restart the kernel and then run again to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happens for me. I had to shut down the notebook (not just the webpage) and then restart. Restarting Kernel also didn't work.

Comment: I think this is something of an answer. But please consider to [edit] and rephrase to reduce the impression of just saying "Me too.".